# HTTP request with data-id and data-sel attributes in Python

Tags: python, http, request

So I'm trying to make an HTTP request in Python using the **requests** library. On the website, there is a link with a **data-id** equal to 7 and a **data-sel** equal to modal. Here is the HTML:

```
`<a href="#submit" class="submit-to-gallery" data-id="7" data-sel="modal"></a>`
```

Basically, when the link `http://example.com/#submit` is visited in the browser, an action is called on the server, right? So can I emulate the link press with all the data in a Python request? Here is what I have scrapped together so far:

```
`import requests
data = {
    'id[]': ['7']
    'sel[]': ['modal']
}
req = requests.get(url='http://example.com/#submit', params=data)
print(req.url)`
```

This doesn't seem to work. Am I doing this wrong? Is there any other information I need to provide?

Answer (score 0):

You can open develop console in the browser and check that http method and data on request.

If the method of HTTP is "Get", you can use the following code.

```
payload = {'id': 'value1', 'sel': 'value2'}
r = requests.get("http://example.com/#submit", params=payload)
```

Chrom Develop Console:
[image]